# calculate sum of two values on the base of field name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Add values between two fields on the base of month names  I have fields in the table from January to December and I want to calculate only the sum between May to September.
code I have tried but it's not working for me

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,GETDATE()) 'Month Name'
(
select top 1 Column_name='May'
from Information_schema.columns 
where Table_name like 'session2021'
)
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly do you want. Please show us your table schema, sample data and required result

Comment: Thank you for your response i have added image please review it thank you again

Comment: It's not clear with the information you provide, but it seems yo should add a clause in the where (month >= 5 and month <= 9)

Comment: please avoid posting image. use formatted text instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have fields in the table from January to December and I want to calculate only the sum between May to September.

I would expect:

```
select May + June + July + August + September as my_sum
from the_table;
```

You should fix your data model so you have one row per *month*, rather than putting the months in separate columns.

Comment: I need to give the only two-month name, for example, one value is march and the other is September and it calculates the sum like ( march+april+may+june+july+aug+sep)